Referencing a cell in a Table in Google sheets
Google sheets have introduced the Tables feature. We can now refer to an entire column using Employees[Name] . Excel had this feature since long. In Excel you can even reference individual cells on a given row such as MATCH(Employees[@Name], Employess[Name],0). The @ implies we are working on the present row and looking for a single cell. This does not seem to work in Google sheets. It shows an error. Is anyone aware of how cells can be referenced in a Table using name of the column?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3ZCE_9IvVyhrb-uK-ofMT3f0H_En1SfLSjbC8oyZlk/edit?usp=drive_link

The match() formula shown in the question will return the ordinal of a value, which is usually not too useful. With a column of unique values, it will simply be the same as row(). Is this an XY problem?

This syntax will get the value in the current row of the Name column in the Employees table:
=Employees[Name]

To get the ordinal of the first matching name in the table that matches the name in the current row within the table, use this:
=match(Employees[Name], Employees[Name], 0)

For the to work, the formula cell must be within the table.
To get the value in a cell on some other row than the current row within the column, use chooserows(), like this:
=chooserows(Employees[Name], 3)

See Use table references in Google Sheets.

This syntax does not work in the case of a MATCH function invocation. Employees[Name]  refers to the entire column.

It is unclear what you are asking. You are now explicitly specifying match(), while you originally asked "how cells can be referenced in a Table using name of the column". The answer I gave you answered the latter, but I edited the answer to also show how to get any specific cell within the column.

I have created a sample here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3ZCE_9IvVyhrb-uK-ofMT3f0H_En1SfLSjbC8oyZlk/edit?usp=drive_link .  The cell marked in green needs to use a column name. That is not working. The syntax of column name works when you want to obtain a single value and show it in a cell. But it does not work when you want to obtain the single value and use it in a function that deals a single value and  with an entire range.

One solution for the case presented in the sample spreadsheet is =match(Table1_2[[#TOTALS],[Name]], Table1_2[Name], 0), or maybe more easily just =match(B5, .... It is unclear why you would need to get the ordinal. Please edit the question and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Updated the Solution tab. The TOTAL does not work.

Added a match() formula in the answer that refers to the current row.

The match formula with the column name does not work in the sample online sheet as it causes a spill in the last row.

Sorry. Its not a spill but an error in the last row.

Try this
I have no information with your dataset. @ is just a short hand for [#This Row] in Excel, [#This Row] exists on Google Sheet. Maybe this is what you need.
Edit:
To Match the Data on the Shared Spreadsheet.
=IFNA(match(Employees[[#This Row],[Name]], Employees[Name], 0),"")

Sample Output

Note: The Google Sheets auto changes the formula but the shared formula is how it started.

I have created a sample here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3ZCE_9IvVyhrb-uK-ofMT3f0H_En1SfLSjbC8oyZlk/edit?usp=drive_link. The cell marked in green needs to use a column name. That is not working.

On your most recent  Sheet. I have tried the same principle of [#This Row]. Sharing What I have used to get your expected result =IFNA(match(Employees[[#This Row],[Name]], Employees[Name], 0),"")

You may add a column to demonstrate. The [#This row] automatically changes to absolute reference and removes the field name.
